# How to make the boost::apply_visitor a friend-function of the class-visitor?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant, friend-function

How to make the `boost::apply_visitor` (either of two variants) a friend-function of class-visitor?

I have tried the following: `friend result_type boost::apply_visitor<>(decltype(*this) &, instruction_type const &);`, but this does not work. `*this` derived from `boost::static_visitor` (or have `using result_type = ...;` typedef) and instruction type is the `boost::variant` of some specific types. `*this` have all required `operator ()`-s in `private` section.

What is the right form of such declaration?

Comment: Why would it _need_ to be? This looks like unnecessary complication to me. `apply_visitor` expects a `static_visitor<>` derived class, with a public interface. Just supply it :/

Comment: @sehe My visitor is class template. So I must place all the logic in the header, but I want to have "some residual amount" of `private`ness (to provide encapsulation as much as I can).

Comment: Then employ pimpl for the 'private' stuff. You can't hide the public interface. Not should you have to.

Comment: But it is redundant to employ the **pimpl** for implementation of visitor. In our case **impl** should be the class template too (with visible interface).

Comment: Try using 'template<class> friend class ::boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor;'

Answer (score 3):

If you insist, you could wrap your actual visitor in a visitor that exposes the required interface, and declare *that* as a friend of your visitor-impl (that now combines the impl and visitor concepts).

*(The "good" (cough) thing here is that there is not need for the `impl` to be polymorphic or dynamically allocated.)*

Here's a stratight-forward proof of concept:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

namespace detail
{
    template <typename R, typename Wrapped>
        struct WrapVisitor : boost::static_visitor<R>
    {
        template <typename... T> R operator()(T&&... args) const { return _wrapped(std::forward<T>(args)...); }

        WrapVisitor(Wrapped&& wrapped) : _wrapped(std::move(wrapped)) {}
     private:
        Wrapped _wrapped;
    };
}

template <typename R, typename Wrapped>
detail::WrapVisitor<R, Wrapped> wrap(Wrapped&& wrapped) {
    return { std::forward<Wrapped>(wrapped) };
}
```

And here's how you'd use it with a demo visitor that hides *all* implementation details:

```
class PrivateVisistorImp : protected boost::static_visitor<double>
{
    double operator()(int i)    const { return -i;   }
    double operator()(double d) const { return d*10; }

    friend detail::WrapVisitor<double, PrivateVisistorImp>;
};
```

Of course, it has the cost of needing to instantiate the *wrapped* visitor at the call site:

```
int main()
{
    using Var = boost::variant<int, double>;

    Var a = 3.14, b = 42;
    auto w = wrap<double>(PrivateVisistorImp());
    std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(w, a) << "\n";
    std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(w, b) << "\n";
}
```

See it all **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff4ba806c87f0a80)**

Comment: I completely fail to understand what you wanted to say there. For entertainment value, here's [a version that even 'lifts' `noexcept`-ness of the wrapped visitor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23f7129872bd450e) :)